# Does a force being applied in an ideal case to an object of infinite mass where there is no friction always result in an acceleration?

Tags: particle-physics

So if yes is your answer to my question then does that mean that the property of the object that resists this acceleration ie.(mass) if is infinity in the equation acceleration= force/mass would'nt make a change to this scenerio..
thnx
well i came across this problem when i was learning the work energy  equation 
1/2 m(Vf)^2 - 1/2  m(Vi)^2 = F*d -(1)
and i was analysing which would be the cases where the K.E would remain the same or in other words putting  R.H.S = F*d = 0
which would be possible at case 1: (F=0,d=0)- object at rest
                           case 2: (F=0, d= some value) - object at constant velocity
               and finally case 3: (F=some value, d=0) - ????
which i am not able to convinvce my self bcoz if there is no displacement,there's no velocity and hence no acceleration which should then correspondingly mean that there should'nt be any force...

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking in the body of this post, but the answer to the title question is No. Not only is infinite mass completely impossible, a force on infinite mass (under Newtonian mechanics) would yield no acceleration

Comment: $F=ma$ so $m=F/a$. You can talk about infinities and zero-divide if you like. Seems a little silly.

Comment: So infinite mass is impossible, but infinite spacetime and infinite electric field (electron standard model) is, apparently.  

(More) seriously, since there are a finite number of masive particles in the universe, there there is no infinite mass.  So your question is not relevant to this universe, as the premise is invalid.

Comment: Instead of using chatspeak like "thnx" or "bcoz", it might be better if you edit your question to use proper English and grammar. Remember, this is a site for professional physicists and professional physicists are uncool. That means we probably don't understand your crazy new-age way of speaking and it would serve you better to talk in the manner we would understand

Comment: I'm sorry for my language,Sir and about the question this is what really happened i came across the work-energy theorm today and was taking different cases where the kinetic energy of the object would remain the same by putting the (Force*displacement){F.d}= 0,which i observed could be possible in 3 cases, [1]- when the object is at rest and no force is acting on it ie. (F=0,d=0), [2]- when the object is moving with constant velocity (d=constant) which does'nt require a force so(F=0,d= some constant value) and [3]-(force= some constant,d = 0),which i don't understand as to how it works

Answer (score 1):

For gravity, it doesn't matter whether or not mass is infinite, since the gravitational acceleration $\vec{g}$ is independent of the accelerated mass:

$$ \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\vec{F}_G}{m} = \vec{g} \ne 0 $$
if the attracting mass is finte. This is what one calls [equivalence principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) and which makes gravity quite special, since every object "falls" at the same rate of acceleration, regardless of the properties of that object.

But all other forces we know of don't vary linearly for big $m$ leaving usually
$$ \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\vec{F}}{m} = 0 $$
such that the particle's acceleration is zero.

Still, there is a problem with infinite mass, because in classical gravitational mechanics this would imply an infinte counter-force on a second object, according to [Newton's third law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion). If this object had finite mass there would be an instantanious change in position as soon as this force would be applied. This is problematic, because due to every day observations, things move smoothly and not in an instantanious manner.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, physically this can never happen, but as a hypothetical the answer is no. Because mass acts as inertia and if an object has an infinite amount of it, it will never accelerate.
\begin{equation}
\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\vec{F}}{m} = \vec{a} = 0
\end{equation}
This is of course if you literally mean infinity, if you mean *a lot of* then the answer is yes. The acceleration in that case would just be negligible.

Answer (score -1):

In physics infinity does not means that actual infinity.It only means that the parameter that we taken is something very much bigger than other parameters. the answer of your question is "yes".Mathematicaly F get the value of zero only indicate it is infinitesimally small